# Change operator precedence

Tags: algorithm, abstract-syntax-tree, operator-precedence

What would be the best way to change operator precedence for a concrete expression?

For example I have a class:

```
class A(){ 
   def multiply(a) { 
       ... 
   } 

   def plus(a) { 
       ... 
   } 

   def minus(b) {
       ...
   }

} 

a = new A() 
b = new A() 
c = new A() 

d = a + (b - c) * d
```

As multiplication has higher precedence than `+` and `-` I get an AST of form

```
  +
 / \
a   *
   / \
  -   d
 / \
b   c
```

What would be the easiest way to convert it to a tree where `*` has lower precedence than `+` and `-`. I assume that parentheses are allowed only to group `-` and `+`, i.e. an expression `(a * b - c) * d` is not valid and should be not expected as an input.

Comment: I'd be careful: operator overloading *can* introduce confusion and changing the operator precedence could introduce even more!

Comment: it's dsl so should be ok

Comment: You mention 'right shift' without identifying the symbol that denotes it.  Is `*` the symbol for 'right shift'?

Comment: The best way would be to simply declare other operator precedences in your grammar, and also to put the rules on parentheses in there. Which, obviously, means using your own parser, but changing the fundamental syntax rules inside some language is just confusing. Not that I could deduce from your question what parser or language you are actually using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could simply add parentheses to your code. This will likely make your code a lot more easily understood than using an AST transformation.

Answer (score 3):

You **could** change it using an AST transformation, but it would be a tricky thing to get right...

If you load your script into the GroovyConsole, and then open the AST browser, you will see this tree for the assignment:

```
Binary - ( d = ( a & ( b >> c ) ) )
  Variable - d
  Binary - ( a & ( b >> c ) )
    Variable - a
    Binary - ( b >> c )
      Variable - b
      Variable - c
```

So as you can see, the nodes are executed based on default operator precedence, and a tree of `org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.BinaryExpression` and `org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.VariableExpression` AST nodes is created.

You would need to write an AST transform that scanned the tree for BinaryExpression nodes and then re-order these trees so that they are sorted by your own precedence for the `operation` field.

Or, you could just use parentheses in your code as Don suggests :-)

Comment: it's actually a dsl, so introducing will add some noise. Also if user will use parentheses i will not be able to get this information in AST, right?